# htaccess url in xampp - how my url is localhost

Tags: .htaccess

This is how I'm going to your design and content on the website, so it must first develop on localhost first

I have looked at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVkR1FHBigk

it just has to be when I'm done I just like to throw it over to the service where I need to right it somewhere / customize it according to how my url is on the website;)

at present I write for example index.php so it will be / Cover / and not just the front /

For example if I write write on to the other side then I say index.php, but would like that it was / Cover /

For example, when I need to download a picture and I will do like this:

```
<img src="img/nyhederinto/hej.png">
```

They want to have like this

```
<img src="/img/nyhederinto/hej.png">
```